# Two or more letters in a string

Tags: regex

I am struggling to find the solution to this exercise:

Give regular expressions for the following English sentences over the alphabet {a, b}:
All strings containing two or more "a".

I know how to find 2 or more "a", but not sure how to include it in another strings formed by "a" and "b".

`aa(aa)*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can write a regex containing `a` and `b` where number of `a` are two or more.

```
^(?:b*ab*){2,}$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ADInJi/1)**

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The substantially quicker and preferred way to do this:

`^b*ab*a[ab]*$`

Benchmarks

```
Regex1:   ^b*ab*a[ab]*$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.21 s,   205.99 ms,   205989 µs
Matches per sec:   728,194


Regex2:   ^(?:b*ab*){2,}$
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.33 s,   327.00 ms,   326998 µs
Matches per sec:   458,718
```